# Why does python use 'assert test' instead of 'assert(test)'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-lawyer

In python2, it's possible to use `print 123` and `print(123)`, and both `assert True` and `assert(True)`.

In python3, why can't I use `print 123` while being able to use `assert True`?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `assert` is not a function.

Long answer:

When python3 came out, it changed(or, removed) `print sth` syntax, because `print` became a builtin **function** so it should be **called**.

Although `assert` can be used like a function(`assert(True)`), it isn't a function - it actually is a **syntax** in [python3 grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), like print in python2 [was](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/grammar.html).

Unlike `print`, of which the type is `class 'builtin_function_or_method'` when you execute `type(print)`, when you try to `type(assert)` or `type(if)` you'll get this:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So you can't use `print 123` while using `assert True` because these two are different.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, both `print` and `assert` are statements (like `if`, `while`, `def`, etc). In this case, the parens are not interpreted as the function call operator but just as plain parens, forcing the evaluation of their content, which in this case is a no-op and is actually considered unpythonic.

In Python 3, `print()` became a function so you *must* call it. `assert` is still a statement so it works just like in Python 2.